# Use column names of one df to map values into rows of another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to map the values of one df (based on its column names) into the values of another df. Code below – however, here is also a screenshot to illustrate my question:

[image]

For example, row 0 of the "desired" df matches the *category* of the row values in the "keys" df. But the specific values are taken from the "values" df. For example, in the desired df, `desired['block_1'][0]` is `values['apple'][0]`, `desired['block_2'][0]` is `values['orange'][0]`, `desired['block_3'][0]` is `values['pear'][0]`, and `desired['block_4'][0]` is `values['berry'][0]`.

Is there a way to do this cleanly? Thank you! Code below.

keys df:

```
block_1 = ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple']
block_2 = ['orange', 'berry', 'pear', 'pear', 'orange', 'berry']
block_3 = ['pear', 'pear', 'orange', 'berry', 'berry', 'orange']
block_4 = ['berry', 'orange', 'berry', 'orange', 'pear', 'pear']

keys = pd.DataFrame({'block_1': block_1, 'block_2': block_2, 'block_3': block_3, 'block_4': block_4})
```

values df:

```
apple = [('apple_1', 'apple_3', 'apple_2'), 
         ('apple_2', 'apple_3', 'apple_1'), 
         ('apple_3', 'apple_1', 'apple_2'), 
         ('apple_3', 'apple_2', 'apple_1'), 
         ('apple_1', 'apple_2', 'apple_3'), 
         ('apple_2', 'apple_1', 'apple_3')]
pear = [('pear_1', 'pear_3', 'pear_2'), 
         ('pear_2', 'pear_3', 'pear_1'), 
         ('pear_3', 'pear_1', 'pear_2'), 
         ('pear_3', 'pear_2', 'pear_1'), 
         ('pear_1', 'pear_2', 'pear_3'), 
         ('pear_2', 'pear_1', 'pear_3')]
orange = [('orange_1', 'orange_3', 'orange_2'), 
         ('orange_2', 'orangee_3', 'orange_1'), 
         ('orange_3', 'orange_1', 'orange_2'), 
         ('orange_3', 'orange_2', 'orange_1'), 
         ('orange_1', 'orange_2', 'orange_3'), 
         ('orange_2', 'orange_1', 'orange_3')]
berry = [('berry_1', 'berry_3', 'berry_2'), 
         ('berry_2', 'berry_3', 'berry_1'), 
         ('berry_3', 'berry_1', 'berry_2'), 
         ('berry_3', 'berry_2', 'berry_1'), 
         ('berry_1', 'berry_2', 'berry_3'), 
         ('berry_2', 'berry_1', 'berry_3')]
          
values = pd.DataFrame({'apple': apple, 'pear': pear, 'orange': orange, 'berry': berry})
```

desired output:

```
desired = pd.DataFrame({'block_1': [('apple_1', 'apple_3', 'apple_2'), 
                                     ('apple_2', 'apple_3', 'apple_1'), 
                                     ('apple_3', 'apple_1', 'apple_2'), 
                                     ('apple_3', 'apple_2', 'apple_1'), 
                                     ('apple_1', 'apple_2', 'apple_3'), 
                                     ('apple_2', 'apple_1', 'apple_3')], 
                        'block_2': [('orange_1', 'orange_3', 'orange_2'),
                                  ('berry_2', 'berry_3', 'berry_1'),
                                 ('pear_3', 'pear_1', 'pear_2'),
                                  ('pear_3', 'pear_2', 'pear_1'),
                                  ('orange_1', 'orange_2', 'orange_3'),
                                  ('berry_2', 'berry_1', 'berry_3')],
                        'block_3': [('pear_1', 'pear_3', 'pear_2'),
                                  ('pear_2', 'pear_3', 'pear_1'),
                                  ('orange_3', 'orange_1', 'orange_2'),
                                 ('berry_3', 'berry_2', 'berry_1'),
                                  ('berry_1', 'berry_2', 'berry_3'),
                                  ('orange_2', 'orange_1', 'orange_3')],
                        'block_4': [('berry_1', 'berry_3', 'berry_2'),
                                  ('orange_2', 'orangee_3', 'orange_1'),
                                  ('berry_3', 'berry_1', 'berry_2'),
                                  ('orange_3', 'orange_2', 'orange_1'),
                                  ('pear_1', 'pear_2', 'pear_3'),
                             ('pear_2', 'pear_1', 'pear_3')]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By straightforward *[locating](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)* `keys`(values) in `values`(columns) rowwise (on respective rows):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(keys.apply(lambda x: values.loc[x.name, x].values, axis=1),
                               columns=keys.columns)
print(df)
```

---

```
                       block_1                         block_2                         block_3                          block_4
0  (apple_1, apple_3, apple_2)  (orange_1, orange_3, orange_2)        (pear_1, pear_3, pear_2)      (berry_1, berry_3, berry_2)
1  (apple_2, apple_3, apple_1)     (berry_2, berry_3, berry_1)        (pear_2, pear_3, pear_1)  (orange_2, orangee_3, orange_1)
2  (apple_3, apple_1, apple_2)        (pear_3, pear_1, pear_2)  (orange_3, orange_1, orange_2)      (berry_3, berry_1, berry_2)
3  (apple_3, apple_2, apple_1)        (pear_3, pear_2, pear_1)     (berry_3, berry_2, berry_1)   (orange_3, orange_2, orange_1)
4  (apple_1, apple_2, apple_3)  (orange_1, orange_2, orange_3)     (berry_1, berry_2, berry_3)         (pear_1, pear_2, pear_3)
5  (apple_2, apple_1, apple_3)     (berry_2, berry_1, berry_3)  (orange_2, orange_1, orange_3)         (pear_2, pear_1, pear_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to convert both table into long form, merge/join on common key, then pivot back to wide form with new key:

```
(keys.stack().rename_axis(['idx','block'])
    .reset_index(name='fruit').set_index(['idx','fruit'])
    .join(values.stack().to_frame(name='value').rename_axis(index=['idx','fruit']))
    .reset_index('fruit',drop=True)              # we don't need this `fruit` info in the output
    .set_index('block',append=True)['value']     # pivot routine    
    .unstack('block')
)
```

Output:

```
block                      block_1                         block_2                         block_3                          block_4
idx                                                                                                                                
0      (apple_1, apple_3, apple_2)  (orange_1, orange_3, orange_2)        (pear_1, pear_3, pear_2)      (berry_1, berry_3, berry_2)
1      (apple_2, apple_3, apple_1)     (berry_2, berry_3, berry_1)        (pear_2, pear_3, pear_1)  (orange_2, orangee_3, orange_1)
2      (apple_3, apple_1, apple_2)        (pear_3, pear_1, pear_2)  (orange_3, orange_1, orange_2)      (berry_3, berry_1, berry_2)
3      (apple_3, apple_2, apple_1)        (pear_3, pear_2, pear_1)     (berry_3, berry_2, berry_1)  (orange_3, orange_2, o|range_1)
4      (apple_1, apple_2, apple_3)  (orange_1, orange_2, orange_3)     (berry_1, berry_2, berry_3)         (pear_1, pear_2, pear_3)
5      (apple_2, apple_1, apple_3)     (berry_2, berry_1, berry_3)  (orange_2, orange_1, orange_3)         (pear_2, pear_1, pear_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is other approach: you can iterate rows of `values` and sort the values according to `keys`:

```py
out = values.apply(
    lambda x: [v for v, _ in sorted(zip(x, x.index), key=lambda i: keys.loc[x.name].to_list().index(i[1]))],
    axis=1,
    result_type="expand",
)
out.columns = desired.columns

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                       block_1                         block_2                         block_3                          block_4
0  (apple_1, apple_3, apple_2)  (orange_1, orange_3, orange_2)        (pear_1, pear_3, pear_2)      (berry_1, berry_3, berry_2)
1  (apple_2, apple_3, apple_1)     (berry_2, berry_3, berry_1)        (pear_2, pear_3, pear_1)  (orange_2, orangee_3, orange_1)
2  (apple_3, apple_1, apple_2)        (pear_3, pear_1, pear_2)  (orange_3, orange_1, orange_2)      (berry_3, berry_1, berry_2)
3  (apple_3, apple_2, apple_1)        (pear_3, pear_2, pear_1)     (berry_3, berry_2, berry_1)   (orange_3, orange_2, orange_1)
4  (apple_1, apple_2, apple_3)  (orange_1, orange_2, orange_3)     (berry_1, berry_2, berry_3)         (pear_1, pear_2, pear_3)
5  (apple_2, apple_1, apple_3)     (berry_2, berry_1, berry_3)  (orange_2, orange_1, orange_3)         (pear_2, pear_1, pear_3)
```